# CSS3 Change combobox color when a certain value is selected

Tags: html, css

```css
select[name="combo"] option[value="2"]:checked + select[name="combo"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="combo">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the `select` (not `option`) color, if you pick option 2.
What am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using CSS alone. You will have to use Javascript to make it work - CSS does not offer a "parent" selector.

The `+` selector in CSS is for an element that comes immediately after another element, not being INSIDE it.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0jyg16v/): (using jQuery)

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    switch($this.val()){
        case '2':
            $this.css('color','red');
            break;
        default:
            $this.css('color','black');
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I dont have access to js there, only css. TODA!

Comment: No problems ;) hope this helps.